# core-plot CPTextStyle fontName read-only

Tags: ios4, core-plot

I'm playing with core-plot and I'd like to set font family and size for axis title, so what I did is:

```
CPTextStyle *axisTitleTextStyle = [CPTextStyle textStyle];
axisTitleTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica Bold";
axisTitleTextStyle.fontSize = 14.0;
```

but when I compile I get the error:

```
error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found
```

How can I set font?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CPTextStyle` changed a while back. It is now immutable. There is a mutable variant called `CPMutableTextStyle`.

Comment: Thanks I found it googling around. Thanks for your answer. Max

Answer (score 0):

give this a try

```
CPTextStyle *axisTitleTextStyle = [[CPTextStyle alloc] init];
axisTitleTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica Bold";
axisTitleTextStyle.fontSize = 14.0;

self.graph.titleTextStyle = axisTitleTextStyle;
[axisTitleTextStyle release];
```